# Attach two pivot tables from a worksheet to an email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, pivot, worksheet

I have VBA code which sends a worksheet "Raw Data" via email using a button.

This code creates a specific worksheet as a new workbook and attaches it to an email.

I need to add the pivot tables within a different sheet labelled "Pivot Table". The Pivot Tables have been labelled "COMP" and "NONCOMP".

```vb
Sub Sendemail()
    Dim xOutlookObj As Object
    Dim xEmailObj   As Object
    Dim tempFile    As String
    Dim strbodymsg  As String
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    strbody = "Hello"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW DATA").Copy
    Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook
    
    tempWB.SaveAs Filename:="DGA DATA"
    
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With xEmailObj
        .Display
        .To = "email1@gmail.com"
        .CC = "email2@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Email Test"
        .Attachments.Add tempWB.FullName 
        .HTMLBody = strbody
        If DisplayEmail = FALSE Then
            '.Display
            '.Send 
        End If
    End With
    
    tempWB.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
    Kill tempWB.FullName
    tempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = TRUE
    Set xEmailObj = Nothing
    Set xOutlookObj = Nothing
End Sub
```